# Transistor parameter in Proteus

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit, bjt, npn, proteus

I am just learning the electronics and by the help of proteus I am learning the behaviors of different components.

Could someone please tell me how do I change the Emitter current values of a transistor from its properties in proteus? I took a generic NPN BJT but I want to modify it by my likings. Thanks

Update: adding picture
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here. You can either select a transistor with the desired values, or if you really want to do it with a generic BJT, double click the part to bring up the Edit Component page.

Here you can click the Advanced Properties drop down box and adjust anything you like to your specifications

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply, but I don't see any some of these options in my Proteus.  i am using proteus 8,

Comment: i added the screenshot, you can see

Comment: @Asim if you update to the latest version, you'll have the options I mentioned

Comment: what version do you have? I guess i have recent version. Also i don't see any reason for not including these essential parameter option in any version.

Comment: @Asim I've got version 8.14. The earlier versions should have it too